# Simulating fluid transfer in a pipe

Tags: java, concepts

I know this is a fairly large/broad category, but I've been racking my brain over the last few weeks on how to simulate fluid flowing through pipes. In the environment I'm working, I can have a single pipe segment connect in any of the six directions (the four cardinal directions plus up/down) and am not restricting myself to gravity. My original idea was to have each pipe segment consist of 13 individual "tanks" which can store fluid: 6 input buffers, 6 output buffers, and 1 main buffer. During simulation, each segment would

1. Attempt to push fluid from its output buffers into adjacent pipes/tanks
2. Attempt to refill output buffers from the main buffer
3. Attempt to move fluid from the input buffers into the main buffer

I then ran into the problem where I had fluid left in output buffers that was never being accessed/moved to adjacent pipes (because pipes were not connected on that side), so I created a method that would, if we ever got to the point in which the only fluid in a segment existed in output buffers, take all the fluid back into the main buffer and redistribute it among the output buffers again.

The problem I'm having now is that I end up having pipe segments trap fluid between them (by pushing the fluid back and forth).

I suppose I'm asking whether I've come up with a method that is far too convoluted/overthought or if there is a simpler idea I should think about. (Also, if this is not the appropriate place to be asking this type of question, please let me know.) Thank you for your time!

Comment: ... how accurately do you want to simulate fluid flow?

Comment: Is this for a game, or are you looking for physics-based answers?

Comment: This is for a game, yes. I've already done research on the physics of fluid dynamics, but I don't necessarily need the pipes to follow all of the physical properties of them. (If you want a simple yes/no answer, let's go with "no, I don't need a physics-based answer".) As for the accuracy, it doesn't have to be that accurate. I basically am trying to find a way to move fluid from point A to point B, where the fluid is (for all intents and purposes) being represented as an integer (indicating the volume of a "fluid packet"...if that makes sense at all...